# Unknown error in Titanium map view?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

In my Titanium app I am trying to show map view, I write my below code in button click event

```
var mapview = Titanium.Map.createView({
    mapType: Titanium.Map.STANDARD_TYPE,
    region: {latitude:37.389569, longitude:-122.050212,
            latitudeDelta:0.1, longitudeDelta:0.1},
    animate:true,
    regionFit:true,
    userLocation:false
});
win.add(mapview);
```

when I used above one, my getting stopped unfortunately.
error :Unable to resolve superclass of Lti/modules/titanium/map/TiMapActivity; (678)

Please do help for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ti.Map.createView](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Map-method-createView) was deprecated in version 3.2.0, which is the version I am assuming you are using.

Instead use this [replacement module](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Modules.Map). That guide will show you how to integrate with both iOS and Android.

Essentially, [download this module, and install it](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/5005), add it to your tiapp.xml of your project:

```
<modules>
    <!-- Add this line to your modules section -->
    <module platform="android">ti.map</module>
</modules>
```

Get a Google Maps API Key, and add it to the android manifest section of your tiapp.xml as detailed in this guide ([Titanium Modules.Map Install Guide and API)](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Modules.Map). Then use it like this:

```
var Map = require('ti.map');
var mapview = Map.createView({mapType:Map.NORMAL_TYPE});
```

Comment: Thanks for response Mr Josiah Hester, I am using 3.2.0 only, will you please give some clarity to me. my app is only for android, how do I implement. I am new to titanium

Comment: Check the linked too guide for the details, but I updated the answer with the general steps.